# translate correctly `for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++)` in R (case `size < 1`)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I used to write for loops in R like

```
for(i in 1:size) { ... }
```

and I thought that it was equivalent of

```
for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) { ... }
```

but I just realised that if `size == 0` R enters the loop anyway because `1:size = [1 0]` and so my code behaves totally wrong.

So, what is the real **standard** way of translating the C for loop I wrote above, such that if `size < 1` the program does not enter the loop?

Comment: `if (size >= 1)  for(i in 1:size) { ... }`

Comment: @jogo yes I ended up with the same workaround, is this the standard way to do this?

Comment: It conserves the logic of the C-for-loop. What do you mean with "standard way"? Who should define the standardisation?

Comment: @jogo I mean, in C I can write a for loop using the while statement, but if I did so then the first time another C programmer read my code he would surely ask me "why didn't you use for instead of that cumbersome while?", I want to avoid this

Comment: Your special programming question is answered (how to conserve the logic of the C-like for-loop to R). Your question about standardisation is a question to answer this for all possible situations - so this is a philosophic question.  Such questions are off-topic on SO because they have to many possible answers (and the answers are opinion based in a great part).

Comment: @jogo I do not agree with you, in this question I am not talking about philosophy or sophism, I want to learn R and I want to learn the best practices in R programming. I do not think that adding an if before almost every loop I write is a good practice.

Comment: Good practice for programming in R is thinking in R (i.e. using the logic of the the constructs in R). Bad practice for programming in R is thinking in C and translate the logic of the C-constructs. This is also the difference between your question and the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`base::seq_len`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/seq):

```
foo <- 2
bar <- 0

for (i in seq_len(foo)) {print(i)}
[1] 1
[1] 2
# No output
for (i in seq_len(bar)) {print(i)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `size` is some size of your object, e.g. `length(vec)` or `nrow(df)`, you can use `seq_along` like below:

```
x = NULL
for (i in seq_along(x)) print(x[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

If size is originally the length of a vector, the standard way is

```
for (i in seq_along(myvector)) {...}
```

which will behave correctly if myvector has length zero. So you *could* even do

```
for (i in seq_along(numeric(size))) {...}
```

but that would be certainly not be considered "standard".

As noted in the comments (and in another answer) the better way is

```
for (i in seq_len(size)) {...}
```

Comment: Second example is redundant, better use `seq_len(size)` as suggested by PoGibas.